# Why does execution stop at wordpress_remote_post() function call?

Tags: php, wordpress, single-sign-on

I am trying to write an SSO plugin for my WordPress multisite and MemberSuite. I'm in the beginning steps, just trying to have the user sign in and get the MemberSuite sign-in token.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
define("MS_API_URL", "http://rest.membersuite.com/swagger/platform/v2/");
define("TENANT_ID", "00000");
define("USER_POOL", "placeholder");
define("CLIENT_ID", "placeholder");

function send_request() {
    $username = $_POST[portalusername];
    $password = $_POST[portalpassword];
    return ms_sign_in($username, $password, USER_POOL, CLIENT_ID);
}

function ms_sign_in($un, $pw, $up, $cid) {
    $url = MS_API_URL . 'storeJWTTokenForUser/' . TENANT_ID;

    $data = array(
        'username' => $un,
        'password' => $pw,
        'userPool' => $up,
        'clientID' => $cid
    );
    $arguments = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'headers' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ),
        'body' => json_encode($data)
    );
    echo "before post";
    $response = wp_remote_post($url, $arguments);
    echo "after post";
    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
    }

    echo $response;
    echo $response['body'];
    return $response['body'];
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <p>body 1</p>
        <?php echo send_request();?>
        <p>body 2</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My form calls the `send_request()` function. As far as I can tell, I've implemented everything the way the MemberSuite documentation [indicates it should be implemented.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAvi2.png) I've included all the necessary values for verification.

However, it appears execution just stops when I reach the line that says `$response = wp_remote_post($url, $arguments);`. The output displays:

body 1

before post

but nothing else. I'd like to know why this happening, if there is any way to fix it, and/or if there is a different way I should go about making the POST request.

Comment: Have you checked the error log yet? If not, enable [WordPress' Debugging Mode](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/), run your script again, then have a look at the debug.log file to see if there are any related warning/error messages.

Comment: WP_DEBUG was set to true, so I just set WP_DEBUG_LOG to true and tried another test. Then I searched from root and it doesn't seem like a debug.log file was created anywhere. Should that be created automatically if the file causes any errors when executed?

Comment: Not sure. You can also just create the file manually and try again.

Comment: I created debug.log in the wp-content folder and ran it again, and it is still empty. The WP_DEBUG_LOG constant was not in the wp-config.php file originally, I added it manually. Could that be causing an issue?

Comment: If you look in the page cabrerahector gave you, you'll see that `WP_DEBUG` doesn't create an error log, it just turns on debugging. You need to use `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to create the error log. See that link again for details.

Comment: Right, I set ```WP_DEBUG_LOG``` to true at the same time that I verified that ```WP_DEBUG``` was set to true, and for some reason it still is not working. I thought the issue might be something with my WordPress install because ```WP_DEBUG_LOG``` was not one of the default constants, I had to add it in.

Comment: Did you try setting *where* the `WP_DEBUG_LOG` log file gets created, so you know where to look for it? Again, the information it all in that page......